Startswith, endswith or "x" in files does not remove files with even number (or acting weird)
When trying to remove files from list with endswith or startwith, i cant find a way to remove files with even numbers. My starting file does include three types of files (stars1-5.xsv, planets1-5.csv and mapping1-5.json) Code is as following:
stars_paths = copy.deepcopy(file_paths)
for files in stars_paths:
    if "stars" not in files:
        stars_paths.remove(files)
        
stars_paths

OUTPUT:
'data\\stars_5.csv',
'data\\stars_4.csv',
'data\\stars_3.csv',
'data\\stars_2.csv',
'data\\stars_1.csv',
'data\\planets_4.csv',
'data\\planets_2.csv',
'data\\mapping_5.json',
'data\\mapping_3.json',
'data\\mapping_1.json'

Or
csv_file_paths = copy.deepcopy(file_paths)
for files in csv_file_paths:
    if files.endswith(".json"):
        print(files)
        csv_file_paths.remove(files)
        
csv_file_paths

OUTPUT:
'data\\stars_5.csv',
'data\\stars_4.csv',
'data\\stars_3.csv',
'data\\stars_2.csv',
'data\\stars_1.csv',
'data\\planets_5.csv',
'data\\planets_4.csv',
'data\\planets_3.csv',
'data\\planets_2.csv',
'data\\planets_1.csv',
'data\\mapping_4.json',
'data\\mapping_2.json'

My mind cant wrap around why it's not working - i really dont know. Please, help. Thank you
I tried copy to deepcopy, i tried changing startswith, endswith or just string in file

You're iterating over a collection that you're removing from. You need to iterate using an index, and decrement the index if you delete, so as not to skip an item.

Don't remove items from a list while you're iterating over the list.

Does this answer your question? Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it in Python (See also this question)

Your problem here is that you are trying to delete an item in the list while iterating over the same list. This causes you to skip some of the items as explained below:
[stars1.json, stars2.json, stars3.json]
      ↑
     i=0 '(File end with .json, so remove)'

[stars2.json, stars3.json]
      ↑
     i=0 '(File removed but index hasnt changed)'

[stars2.json, stars3.json]
                   ↑
                  i=1 '(Increment index but you see we skipped the second file)'

To fix this issue you can simply do:
csv_file_paths = copy.deepcopy(file_paths)
for files in csv_file_paths[:]:  # <- What I changed
    if files.endswith(".json"):
        print(files)
        csv_file_paths.remove(files)

The : for the list index means that you're iterating over a copy of the list meanwhile you're removing elements from the actual list. This will solve your issue with the indent skipping.

When you are trying to select some strings from a list of strings, One possible way is to use filter and pass the function with the condition that you need. For example, If you want to select those files that doesn't contain .json at the end, you can do it like this :
filtered = list(filter(lambda element: not element.endswith('.json'),stars_paths))
print(filtered)

The output will be like :
['data\\stars_5.csv', 'data\\stars_4.csv', 'data\\stars_3.csv', 'data\\stars_2.csv', 'data\\stars_1.csv', 'data\\planets_5.csv', 'data\\planets_4.csv', 'data\\planets_3.csv', 'data\\planets_2.csv', 'data\\planets_1.csv']

You can update the condition with the requirements you want.
